# How to create bottom aligned div elements

Tags: position, alignment

I'm trying to create a couple of elements that are always on the bottom of the page. Currently I'm using this CSS to make it happen.

```
#bottomContainer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Unfortunately, when shrinking the page, these elements cover other parts of the page instead of adjusting like everything else. Is there a way to align div elements with the bottom of the page but still have them be influenced by margin properties and window re-sizing?

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is fixed position your margin-top won't do much.
You'll have to put a margin-bottom on your content element so that it always stays above the bottomContainer.

http://jsfiddle.net/s9t5x/

HTML

```
<div id="bottomContainer"></div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- rest of page content here -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bottomContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content { 
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    counter-reset: cntr; 
}
```

Comment: Setting a bottom margin to the content div above it doesn't work either.

Comment: @user2569544 - If you check the JSFiddle link in my answer the content div and the bottomContainer div are siblings (if by 'above' you mean the content div wraps your bottomContainer this will not work). Without seeing your actual HTML markup there's no way to help you, please add a simplified markup to your question or create a jsfiddle that reproduces your issue.